# matplot scatter plot different colors based on value of the column of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, scatter

Maybe my question was already answered here, but I kinda didn't find a solution working for me.
What I need to do: I want to create a scatter plot from the column of a dataframe and i want different colors for the scatter points based on the value. There are only three values 0,1 and 2 in the column.

I tried it like this:

```
plt.scatter(train.index, train['target'] == 0, c = '#009682', marker = 'o')
plt.scatter(train.index, train['target'] == 1, c = '#808080', marker = ',')
plt.scatter(train.index, train['target'] == 2, c = '#4664aa', marker = '+')
```

train is the dataframe I'm using. I also tried to use plot instead of scatter but it didn't work either. thanks in advance :)

Comment: The easiest way might be use [seaborn scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot)

Comment: I just tried to use seaborn scatterplot but I just wasn't able to use it with the different colors :/ Could you please explain how that would work?

Comment: https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/04/how-to-specify-colors-to-scatter-plots-in-python/